Why is it Incorrect to Use "For" as the Transition Here?
The question (from SAT English practice) asks "Which choice completes the text (the blank) with the most logical transition" for this paragraph:

The Y-Bridge (named for its distinctive Y-shape) was designed to span the confluence of the Muskingum and Licking rivers. _____ it crosses both rivers, Ripley's Believe It Or Not once claimed that the Y-Bridge was the only bridge in the world where it was possible to cross and still end up on the same side of the river, and Amelia Earhart once called Zanesville "the most recognizable city in the country" because of the bridge.

The answer choices are:


For
Because
While
When


My teacher said that the answer was "Because" since it shows a cause and effect relationship, but I was wondering why it can't be "For" for the same reason.

You can use "for" to explain a reason for a statement expressed before. In this sentence, "because" explains the reason/cause for a fact expressed after the clause it heads.

I’m voting to close this question because it picks a weaker choice yet asks for support that "my answer is at least as good as the test answer."

As fev says, 'for' would be ungrammatical here. But I'd hesitate to use any of the suggested alternatives. The reason 'it [is] possible to cross and still end up on the same side of the river' is that the crossing in mind here results in crossing the minor tributary (Licking River) and not the major river (Muskingum River). The statement is misleading, conflating the two crossings. 'It is possible to cross the Licking River and still end up on the same side of the Muskingum River.' Accurate, but hardly very significant.

while it crosses both rivers,

@Lambie May you explain why it is "while"? I believe there are no contrasting statements in the sentence, but I could be wrong. Thank you

You use while at the beginning of a clause to introduce information that contrasts with information in the main clause. Collins Dictionary. It repeats the first sentence idea and then adds something to it.

Because for substitutes for because in special cases, not most of the time, you can't just drop it in.

Consider the same sentence in a different order:

"Ripley's Believe It Or Not" once claimed that the Y-Bridge was the only bridge in the world where it was possible to cross and still end up on the same side of the river because it crosses both rivers

It is described that way because of a specific reason.
It's clear that "because" is the only word that fits here. The example sentence is just reordered but the choice of word is the same.

The difference between for and because.
Consider these two sentences:

I was running hard.
The bus was just about to leave. (This is why I'm running.)

Because is a conjunction. The clause it introduces can be before or after the main clause. So both of these are correct:


I was running hard because the bus was just about to leave.
Because the bus was just about to leave, I was running hard.


Note the comma in the second sentence. It's not needed in the first sentence because the word "because" acts like a comma. It's in the middle of the sentence so we know where the split between the two clauses comes without any further punctuation.
For can also be used as a conjunction, but only after the main clause:


I was running hard, for the bus was just about to leave. (correct)
For the bus was just about to leave, I was running hard. (wrong)


I'm not completely sure why this difference exists, but my instinct is that it relates to the use of for as a preposition:

I gave him money for the groceries.
He studied hard for the final exams.

Here it's clear that we would not say, For the groceries I gave him money. (But we could say, Because he was getting the groceries, I gave him money. It's a different construction.)
You can see this prepositional element in sentence 3. Although for is correctly used as a conjunction, I had to add a comma to ensure this reading. Otherwise we might read, "I was running hard for the bus", and the sentence would be harder to make sense of.

The use of the word “for” to mean “because” is almost completely restricted to poetic or archaic contexts.
“To be loved as to love / For it is in giving that we receive.”
— St. Francis of Assisi
“Boast not thyself of tomorrow, for thou knowest not what a day may bring forth.”
— Proverbs 27:1 (King James Version)
No native English speaker would use “for” to denote causality in a dry paragraph like the one in the text.
It’s more common to see it replace “because of”, followed by a noun, as in “worse for wear” and “I love you, for sentimental reasons”, but that is very different.
I think it’s a terrible idea for an SAT question to rely on understanding of context and register in choosing the “correct” answer — but then I think standardized testing is a terrible idea in general.

There can be an
element of contrast, so While is possible as @Lambie said.
A person would expect to reach the other side of a river
after crossing it.  This

to cross and still end up on the same side of the river

says the unexpected and hence provides the contrast. (We just adopt the above infinitive from Ripley's Believe It Or Not
and leave out the technical analysis.)

OP has asked whether "for" can also be used in the given example:

The Y-Bridge (named for its distinctive Y-shape) was designed to span the confluence of the Muskingum and Licking rivers. _____ it crosses both rivers, Ripley's Believe It Or Not once claimed that the Y-Bridge was the only bridge in the world where it was possible to cross and still end up on the same side of the river, and Amelia Earhart once called Zanesville "the most recognizable city in the country" because of the bridge.

In this example, "because" is the correct choice, as it functions as a subordinating conjunction and fits naturally at the start of the sentence to explain the bridge’s uniqueness.
While "for" can mean "because," it functions as a coordinating conjunction and typically connects two ideas within a sentence. It is used to introduce a reason that follows the main clause.
Placement after the main clause:.

According to the Britannica Dictionary,     "for" is used to introduce a statement that explains why a preceding statement is true..
Example:.
They were certainly there, for I saw them..

In this case, "for" cannot start the sentence because the explanation must follow the main clause, not precede it.
Source: The Britannica Dictionary
How "for" works as a conjunction:.
"For" works best in contexts where it provides a reason as part of the same sentence, rather than starting a new one.
Example:.
The Y-Bridge is unique, for it crosses both rivers.
